# jQuery and map gives weird extra data

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

Here's my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>  
 </body>
</html>
```

I just want to get the text of the li's:

```
$('li').map((i, x) => $(x).text())
// (3) ["one", "two", "three", prevObject: o.fn.init(3), context: document]
```

I feel like there should be a simple way to do this without getting all that extra junk at the end.

**Edit:** The html has been fixed regarding the li tags. The issue is not about bad html.

Comment: why li tag is not closed?

Comment: What exactly is the commented line coming from? Is that a console.log() of the map? It should also be noted `<li>` should be closed with `</li>` to be valid HTML.

Comment: But there's a newline and whitespace in the text-what did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `get()` at the end, otherwise you end up with a jQuery object as jQuery's `$.fn.map` is intended for mapping elements, not text.

```js
var arr = $('li').map((i, x) => $(x).text()).get();

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Adding doc link for more info http://api.jquery.com/map/ "As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array."

Comment: That works. So there's no cleaner way to write that? It feels a little verbose.

Comment: You could do `Array.from($('li').map((i, x) => $(x).text())` since jQuery is an array-like object, but that's even more verbose :P

Comment: Actually I came up with `$('li').get().map(x => $(x).text())` which is a little better. Still clumsy looking though.

Comment: That works too, but then you're no longer use jQuery's map, but the native `Array.map`

Comment: Yeah, as adeneo stated you're now using the array map, which is why you're having to re-wrap the elements with a jQuery object within the project function. To each their own, but I wouldn't consider that a better approach due to the unneeded overhead of wrapping, unwrapping, then re-wrapping of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of not using `</li>`

```js
let data = $('li').map((i, x) => $(x).text()).get();
console.log(data);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
 <body>
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>  
 </body>
</html>
```